# Fix CSS Grid auto expanding height with collapsible div

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm making 2 columns with CSS Grid and with Collapsible div.
The problem is when I expand the one of the collapsible div, 
the other div will also expanding with white space.

Anyone knows how to fix this without making 2 parents div for 2 columns? 
Or using other method instead of CSS-grid?

screenshoot css grid with collapsible div

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to post the relevant code?

Comment: Please add your code using  [Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) tool in the editor below or in jsfiddle, codepen etc

Comment: You cannot use CSS grid for this goal, also no other CSS layout method. Google `masonry javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is more of a masonry kind of layout on an expansion of an accordion. That is not something grid is designed for. The CSS Grid is two dimensional so you are always working with rows and columns at the same time.

Solution: Flexbox

```
#grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: max-content;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    counter-reset: brick;
}


.cell {
    width: 250px;
    flex: 1 0 calc(33.333% - 20px);
    padding: 20px;
    background: #efefef;
}
```

Please check the demo I have created. https://codepen.io/abhishekrajeshirke/pen/NLzLJJ

Hope it answers your question.